# Create new column when using Pandas groupby with two columns and aggregate by multiple metrices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data itself is not realy matter.

I have the following code -

```
# convert timestamp to millisecond
relevant_data_pdf['milli'] = pd.to_datetime(relevant_data_pdf['timestamp']).astype(np.int64) / int(1e6)

# sort (day are values between 1 to 7)
relevant_data_pdf = relevant_data_pdf.sort_values(['id', 'inf_day', 'milli'])

# Calculate the diff between to consecutive rows
relevant_data_pdf['milli_diff'] = relevant_data_pdf.groupby(['id', 'inf_day'])['milli'].diff()

# aggregation by multiple metrices
relevant_data_pdf = relevant_data_pdf.groupby(['id', 'inf_day']).agg(avg=('milli_diff', np.mean),
                                                               median=('milli_diff', np.median),
                                                               max=('milli_diff', np.max),
                                                               min=('milli_diff', np.min))
```

The result I got is something from the form -

```
                     avg     median         max        min
id inf_day                                                
1  1        8.060000e+06  7200000.0  16500000.0   480000.0
   2        1.200333e+06  1771000.0   1800000.0    30000.0
   3        5.400000e+06  5400000.0   7200000.0  3600000.0
2  0        1.800000e+06  1800000.0   3600000.0        0.0
   2        0.000000e+00        0.0         0.0        0.0
   3        0.000000e+00        0.0         0.0        0.0
```

How can make the result be one row for each `id`, such that for each id I will have all the possible columns from the shape of `{inf_day}_{metric_name}`?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways to do this:

```
(df.unstack(-1)
   .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1)) # .sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False) - preserve output in OP, thanks constantstranger!
```

Or

```
df.stack().unstack([-2, -1])
```

In either case, the result will look like

```
inf_day          0                                     1                                           2                                         3                                 
               avg        max     median  min        avg         max     median       min        avg        max     median      min        avg        max     median        min
id                                                                                                                                                                             
1              NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN  8060000.0  16500000.0  7200000.0  480000.0  1200333.0  1800000.0  1771000.0  30000.0  5400000.0  7200000.0  5400000.0  3600000.0
2        1800000.0  3600000.0  1800000.0  0.0        NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN        0.0        0.0        0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
```

---

If you want to flatten the column names after this, I recommend the following approach:

```
unstacked = df.stack().unstack([-2, -1])
unstacked.columns = unstacked.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```

Comment: To match sorting shown in OP, can use this: `.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False)` before flattening column names.